# Use FBLogin to segue Custom View

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, segue

I imported FBLoginKit to my project and it worked.
But while I wanted to make FBLoginButton to segue my app View, it just login to FB's page,couldn't segue the View I specified. Please help me to fix this problem,Thank's!!

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var FBLoginOutlet: FBSDKLoginButton!

@IBOutlet weak var FBLogOut: FBSDKLoginButton!

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    if error != nil {
        print("error")
    } else {
         //The under line didn't work 
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    //The under line didn't work,too.
    let loginvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "startPage")
       self.present(loginvc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: don't use facebook button if you don't want to log in via facebook,

Comment: But that's what I want my code to do. Would you provide an idea or a way to do that for me? Thanks!

Comment: so what exatly you want to do? you want to segue to view controller, so throw away facebook stuff, you don't need that

Comment: OK Thank your response!